# All about list in python3

Tags: list, python-3.x

My code is:

```
    a         = 3.5
    list      = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ]
    bigList   = []
    smallList = []
    for i in list:
        if a < i:
            bigList.append( i )
        else:
            smallList.append( i )
    print( min( bigList ) )
    print( max( smallList ) )
```

My question: Is there a function or a smarter way to get the smaller value and the greater value than a ( example: if a = 6.1, a smaller value will be 6 and a greater value will be 7) without creating two new lists as I did?

Thank you so much.

Comment: `max(num for num in my_list if num < threshold)` and `min(num for num in my_list if num > threshold)`?

Comment: Is it necessary you have to get minimum and maximum from list? I think if you just want the (exmple: if `a = 6.1`) minimum can be obtained using `math.floor(a)` and maximum can be obtained using `math.floor(a+1)` , you have to import package `import math`

Comment: @ŁukaszRogalski Yay. That's what I need. Thanks you so much for such an excellent solution. Much appreciated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `bisect` if the list is sorted:

```
import bisect
insertion_point = bisect.bisect_right(lst, a)
small = lst[max(insertion_point - 1, 0)]
big = lst[min(insertion_point, len(lst) - 1)]
```

This will always return a value in `small` and `big` closest to the relative insertion point.

About [`bisect_right`](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/bisect.html#bisect.bisect_right):

> returns an insertion point which comes after (to the right of) any existing entries of item in list.

- Note: you shouldn't shadow `list` which is part of python. Use `lst` or a similar name.